# Is it possible to acquire and run JDK 7 in production?

Tags: macos, java-7, java

Hi guys : I've seen some increased traffic about java 7 lately, however suns sight isn't clear on wether there do or do not exist java 7 versions that are running in production environments.  Also, I've seen that there is the open jdk 7 resources are available, but i havent been able to find a download...

So - am I just behind the times here with my Java SE 6 ?  What is the release date for java 7 and where is the ideal place to get updates on it ?

Im talking about the JDK here.  And if it is available - where ?  I see alot of "previews" but no official site ?

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***On Java 6:*** no you aren't. Sun's policy was, a major version of JDK expires in a year after a new one is released. <s>I'm not sure about Oracle policies, but it's still a good rule of thumb.</s>

**Update:** [Java 6 End-of-Life policy](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html) is as follows:

- released Dec 2006
- EOL notification Feb 2011
- EOL Jul 2012

> Java SE 6 will no longer be publicly available after July 2012.

***On Java 7:*** the official release date was 2011-07-07, with Update 1 released 2011-10-18.

So everything is here; you're free to use Java 7 in production. Java 6 will be more or less obsolete starting July 2012, but many will continue to use it, anyway: it doesn't make much sense to replace what's not broken.

Regarding ***Java 7 on Mac,*** (emphasis is mine—Alf)

> As of the release of Java for Mac OS X 10.6 Update 3, *the version of Java that is ported by Apple, and that ships with Mac OS X, **is deprecated.***
>   This means that the Apple-produced runtime will not be maintained at the same level, and may be removed from future versions of Mac OS X. The Java runtime shipping in Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard, and Mac OS X 10.5 Leopard, will continue to be supported and maintained through the standard support cycles of those products.

But I assume you're not running your production code on Mac :)

Comment: JDK 7 is available ?  Why is it that everything im seeing is implying its in preview mode (At least for OS X) ?

Comment: Because [Apple JDK is no more](http://nighthacks.com/roller/jag/entry/steve_jobs_comments_on_apple).

Comment: WOW ... So who is going to pick up the slack and keep java alive on OS X ?

Comment: As you read in James Goslings' blog, the only hope is OpenJDK. Unfortunately, as you say, Oracle's Mac OS X version [is still in a preview state](http://jdk7.java.net/macportpreview/), and [OpenJDK doesn't seem to be any better](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/OpenJDK/Mac+OS+X+Port+Project+Status).

Comment: OS X is going to support OpenJDK, probably important not to alienate the java community : http://www.tuaw.com/2010/11/12/java-isnt-dead-on-os-x-as-apple-contributes-to-openjdk/  what about the JRE ?

Comment: JRE is a part of JDK, so if we consider the JDK part solved, everything's already fine. Still, the article you quote is more than a year old; OpenJDK is still not here to catch the train. So I would not put too much hope into it. I have no intent to alienate any community; just explaining what I, a Java developer with a Mac, can see: Apple's done with Java, Oracle is not here (yet?), the community (including the ex-Apple Java group) is yet to catch up.

Comment: Ouch.  Scary  -  I hope someone from apple sees this question and chimes in. If apple is done with java then I'm... Well... Done with...